# Prove that $\psi (z) = \sum_{n =0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(z+n)^2}$

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm doing my complex analysis homework. I have $\psi(z) = \frac{\Gamma'(z)}{\Gamma(z)}$ I need to prove that $$\psi(z) = \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(z+n)^2}$$  I already show that $\psi(z+1) - \psi(z) = \frac{1}{z}$. 
And I have also proved that $$\psi(z) = \frac{1}{z} + \gamma + \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n+z} - \frac{1}{n}$$ where $\gamma$ is the Euler-Mascheroni constant.
However, I was confused about how to prove that the two equations of $\psi(z)$ is equal to each other. Then I'm wondering that maybe this is a typo by my instructor. Could anyone help me with this please? Thanks so much!
 **UPDATE:** Here's some properties I have proved about Gamma function. We define when $s>0$, $$\Gamma(s) = \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-t} t^{s-1} dt$$ And I also know the Weierstrass' formula for $\frac{1}{\Gamma(s)}$, which is $$\frac{1}{\Gamma(s)} = se^{\gamma s} \prod_{n = 1}^{\infty} = ((1 + \frac{s}{n}) e^{-\frac{s}{n}})$$where $\gamma$ is the Euler-Mascheroni constant. And I also know the property that $\Gamma(s+1) = s\Gamma(s)$. And the analytic continutation of $\Gamma(s)$ is $$\Gamma(s) = \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n}}{n! (n+s)}$$
 **SOLUTION:** I have the equation $\psi(z) = \frac{1}{z} + \gamma + \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n+z} - \frac{1}{n}$. Then I differentiate both sides with respect to $z$. Then I get $$\psi ' (z) = -\frac{1}{z^2} + \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} -\frac{1}{(n + z)^2}$$which is equal to $$\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(z + n)^2}$$

Comment: What definition did you start with for $\Gamma?$ What have you already proven about $\Gamma?$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I've updated my post about the properties and definition of $\Gamma$ I've known and proved.

Comment: It should be the derivative $$\psi'(z) = \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(z+n)^2}$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The digamma function $\psi(z)$ is ***not*** represented by the series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac1{(z+n)^2}$.  Rather, the derivative of the digamma function has a representation given by

$$\psi'(z)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac1{(z+n)^2}\tag1$$

To see this, we begin with the series representation of the digamma function for $z\notin \mathbb{N}_{n<0}$, as given by

$$\begin{align}
\psi(z)&=-\gamma+\sum_{n=0}^\infty \left(\frac1{n+1}-\frac{1}{n+z}\right)\\\\
&=-\gamma +\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{z-1}{(n+1)(n+z)}\tag2
\end{align}$$

We may differentiate the series in $(2)$ term by term to arrive at

$$\begin{align}
\psi'(z)&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac1{(n+1)(n+z)}-\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{z-1}{(n+1)(n+z)^2}\\\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac1{(n+z)^2}\end{align}$$

as was to be shown!

Comment: Thank you for your answer!

Comment: I've also updated my post.

Comment: You're welcome.  My pleasure.